# Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink

Tags: node.js, npm, web-worker

I am trying to install `webworker-threads` into my Node project and I keep running onto this error:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -\> '../Desktop/NODE/nodejs_advanced/node_performance/node_modules/.bin/mime'
```

What could be the issue?

```
npm ERR! path ../mime/cli.js
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/home/mutua/Desktop/NODE/nodejs_advanced/node_performance/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/home/mutua/Desktop/NODE/nodejs_advanced/node_performance/node_modules/.bin/mime'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/home/mutua/Desktop/NODE/nodejs_advanced/node_performance/node_modules/.bin/mime'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -13,
npm ERR!     code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!     path: '../mime/cli.js',
npm ERR!     dest: '/home/mutua/Desktop/NODE/nodejs_advanced/node_performance/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/home/mutua/Desktop/NODE/nodejs_advanced/node_performance/node_modules/.bin/mime'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../mime/cli.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/home/mutua/Desktop/NODE/nodejs_advanced/node_performance/node_modules/.bin/mime',
npm ERR!   parent: 'node_performance'
npm ERR! }
```

I was expecting a seamless installation but I keep running onto a PERMISSION DENIED Error.

Comment: Have you tried to reach out to the maintainer of that project? Or looking at their issues on GitHub?

Comment: did you solve this issue ?

Comment: @Hessah, Not yet